# A property of centroid

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $\triangle ABC$ be an arbitrary triangle and let $G$ be its centroid. Three medians are denoted by $AD,BE,CF$. I am attempting to show that the circumcentres of $\triangle AGF,\triangle GFB,\triangle BGD,\triangle DGC,\triangle CGE,\triangle EGA$ lie on a circle. I've worked on the problem several days by some analytic means and find it hard to solve, so I wonder if there is an elegent way to prove the result, and is there a description of the center of this circle?

Any advise or help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Each triangle has 3 excenters, which one you are talking about? All three?

Comment: @Oldboy Sorry, that was a typo, it should be circumcentre. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Here is another Conjecture on Six Concyclic Circumcenter : https://commons.hostos.cuny.edu/mtrj/wp-content/uploads/sites/30/2022/04/v14n1-Problem-Corner.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem describes famous [Van Lamoen circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Lamoen_circle).

The proof is not elementary (won't fit a single sheet of paper, I mean) and you can find several diferent ones on the web. Actually, this is the problem of the Olympic caliber. Two different proofs:

[The Lamoen circle](https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://docslide.net/google-reader/circle-and-triangle-olympiad-lamoen), Darij Grinberg

[Another proof of van Lamoen’s Theorem and Its Converse](http://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2005volume5/FG200516.pdf), 
Nguyen Minh Ha

The hexagon $A_bA_cB_aB_cC_aC_b$ has other interesting properties. For example, the opposite sides are parallel and main diagonals are of equal length.

[image]